# Django gabarit tag - how to return a variable as string instead of text

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a `django project`. I came accross a trouble. I have an `instance` somewhere in my `view` called `roadnetwork`. In my `html(or js) template`, I would like to get this instance name via  `{{roadnetwork.name}}` as a string and not a text. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You mean a JavaScript string?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I need this variable in my javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|json_script`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) to store the text in a special `<script … > … </script>` template node, and then load it with the given id.

This thus looks as:

```
{{ roadnetwork.name|json_script:'roadname' }}
<script>
const roadnetwork = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('roadname').textContent);
# ⋮
</script>
```

Comment: Lots of thanks, that's what I was looking for. Could you please , just replace `hello-data` by `roadname` for the future user?